# Hibernate throwing ConstraintViolationException when executing delete statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are tons of questions and answers online regarding to this exception but none of them resolve my issue. I have very simple two entities - one is category and the other one is item. Category has one to many relationship with item. I don't have any problem with insert statement. But when I try to delete Category, hibernate throws "org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement" exception because of foreign key constraint ("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CATEGORY". The conflict occurred in database "shop", table "dbo.ITEM", column 'CATEGORY_ID'."). So, apparently cascading annotation is not working. What am I missing here?

This is what my code looks like :

```
 int rows = em.createQuery("delete from CATEGORY where id = :id")
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .executeUpdate();
```

**CATEGORY ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

......//Getters and Setter
```

**ITEM ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @Size(max = 150)
    private String name;

....//Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: Instead of using native queries, try to delete using JPA delete function

Comment: @Viswa That's not a native query, it's a JPQL query. `em.remove` would be cleaner but would execute the identical JPA logic. The problem is the cascade.

Comment: @chrylis after googling more, my understanding is JPA spec doesn’t cover cascade for delete. So executing delete JPQL statement would result in FK constraint exception. The solution is to use hibernate remove like Viswa said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Cascade property has not effect with JPQL because JPA doesn’t support cascade delete (at this point). If you want JPQL to work, cascade needs to be baked into schema. That means removing foreign key constraint and adding cascade delete constraint. Otherwise, foreign key constraint exception will be thrown. If you don't want to bake cascade into schema, another option is use hibernate remove method on each object.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting data, you need to use Transaction.

You can use UserTransaction:

```
UserTransaction utx = entityManager.getTransaction(); 

try { 
    utx.begin(); 
    businessLogic();
    utx.commit(); 
} catch(Exception ex) { 
    utx.rollback(); 
    throw ex; 
}
```

or Spring @Transactional

```
@Transactional
public void businessLogic() {
... use entity manager inside a transaction ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I do have transactional annotation. If I don't, it would be a different exception not the foreign key constraint one i'm having right now.